# Which Java classes can get and cast system properties, and why?

Tags: java, system-properties

Any system property set with `-Dkey=value` can be retrieved as a String using `System.getProperty("key")`. But you can also get certain system properties casted to a specific type, e.g.:

```
Boolean.getBoolean("key"); //Returns true if value==true
Integer.getInteger("key"); //Returns value if exists & is number, else null
Long.getLong("key"); //Ditto as for Integer
```

Are there any other classes with a `static getSomeClass(String systemPropertyKey)` method? Why don't `Byte`, `Float`, or `Double` have them, but the other primitive wrappers do (or what *might* be the reason)?

Comment: I've always wondered why Boolean, Integer, and Long have those methods, since they don't really relate to the function of their associated classes.  I suspect they're accidents of history and would not be provided if it were done all over from scratch.  They really belong in System or in some separate Properties class.

Comment: @HotLicks Exactly my thoughts. Those methods are attached to the wrong classes, and misleadingly named.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look into the implementation of for example `Boolean::getBoolean` you will notice that the wrapper types simply offer some convenience for reading `System::getProperty`:

```
public static boolean getBoolean(String name) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        result = toBoolean(System.getProperty(name));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
    }
    return result;
}

private static boolean toBoolean(String name) {
    return ((name != null) && name.equalsIgnoreCase("true"));
}
```

The above method is only a convenience for retrieving a typed property or a default value if the given value is illegal.

By my knowledge, only the wrapper types `Boolean`, `Long` and `Integer` offer such methods. (The `String` type does for example [not offer such a method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/), other than implied by your question.') The rational is probably the fact that these primitive types are common for properties that are handed over as a system property. You would for example not normally require a user to offer an XML structure by command line, just to name one example.

Reading a system property is a requirement that is spread all over the Java class library. One could have put a similar set of convenience methods into an internal package but I guess that the authors of the JDK libraries considered this to be a requirement to be also relevant to users outside of the JCL and made it public. In the end, the wrapper types are meant to offer some convenience for dealing with primitives. I would not know a better place than the wrapper types to put these methods.

As pointed out by Pablo, decimal values are not considered a good value for a command line property as the decimal separator it is locale dependent. Also, I cannot think of such a property used in the JCL. This would explain why a similar method is missing from `Float` and `Double`. Also, because `byte`, `short` and `char` are represented at `int`s at runtime, I would not see a particular use case for these values either what would explain their absence.

Comment: `Float` or `Double` would have a problem with the Locale of the system: in some places the decimal separator is the dot `.` and in others is the comma `,`. Also precision could be a problem.

Answer (score -5):

You can create a BigDecimal and do the conversion from that.

```
String myNumber = "10.23";
BigDecimal myDecimal = new BigDecimal(myNumber);
double myDouble = myDecimal.doubleValue();
int myInt = myDecimal.intValue();
long myLong = myDecimal.longValue();
BigInteger myBigInteger = myDecimal.toBigInteger();
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.